# Ore and Invariant basis number.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian

A ring $\rm R$ (unitary, associative, non-commutative) has IBN (invariant basis number) if ${\rm R}^n\simeq {\rm R}^m$ (as left-modules) implies $n=m$.

$\rm R$ is left-Ore if $\rm Ra\cap Rb$ is non-zero for all non-zero $(a,b)\in{\rm R}^2$.

Every left-Noetherian ring $R$ both is left-Ore and has IBN.

> **Question.** Is there a left-Ore ring that does not have IBN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition you have given for "left Ore ring" is not the standard one. What you have written is in fact equivalent to $R$ being a **left uniform ring**, by which I mean that the intersection of any two nonzero left ideals is nonzero.

It's easy to see why such rings always have IBN. Such a ring has left uniform dimension $1$, and $R^n$ would have uniform dimension $n$. But uniform dimension is well-defined, so $R^n\cong R^m$ would imply this module has two different uniform dimensions, a contradiction.

---

The normal definition of a left Ore ring is this: a ring is called *left-Ore* if the set of regular elements is left permutable.

The pool of examples of non IBN rings is not well-known, so we don't have much to lose if we check the few known examples.

You probably know that $End_k(V)$ does not have the IBN if $V$ is infinite dimensional over $k$. It's also von Neumann regular since $V$ is a semisimple $k$ module. But **all von Neumann regular rings are left and right Ore** since they are equal to their rings of classical quotients (see for example Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* p 303 in the middle.

Comment: Here's the [DaRT query](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?has=100&lacks=64) for later in case more examples show up; however, since I'm only aware of one other class of non IBN rings, I don't anticipate many examples pouring in...

Comment: The DaRT query is for the latter half of the post, of course.

Comment: I guess I am considering integral domains, for wich the 2 conditions 'left Ore' and 'left uniform' are equivalent, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Drike That's correct!